# check whether you are in community home page or not

Tags: community, lightning, napili

I am using Napili Community template and I want to check on load whether the user is on the home page or any other page?

Is there any option to check like that?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to visit [ask] and take the [tour] in order to get familiar with the forum. Prior to asking here, did you do any research? what is your current use case? what have you tried so far? As is, it doesn't look like you have put much effort in researching  what you are asking. If so, what have you tried so far that doesn't seem to work? Please update your post accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I write the solution again, but detailed.

In a Napily CommunitTemplate,
[image]

You can add a Lightnin Custom component, for example, in TEMPLATE HEADER TOP
[image]
This section is shared for all Community.

The custom component, must handle the init event, and in the funcition of the event you can call javascript window.location.href

Custom Component Code
(component)

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

(JS controller)

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var pathlength = window.location.href.split('?')[0].split('\/').length;
        alert('you are on: '+window.location.href.split('?')[0].split('\/')[pathlength - 1]);
    }
})
```

When you Enter in home page, you get a ""
[image]

And when you enter in other pages, you get the last path (is an example, you can get as you want from the current URL)
[image]

The solution works! please remove bad comments and thumbs up if work for you.

If you have some doubt contact with me without problems

Comment: I guess in URL, a page might or not have a `/s` after subdomain? Basically its reads the URL.

Comment: Its an example for my community, you can check the URL as you want. Perhaps this is a workaround, but works Ok! You know some other method? Please show me!

Comment: Ok, we can get your other answer deleted as this is much more helpful. I'll see if it works for me in a dev org.

Comment: I was just checking whether if there is a standard way of doing this. thanks for the help.